# Нужно добавить в поле sum значение собственного поля + значение вложенных строк

Tags: php, рекурсия

Имеется таблица из которой я делаю выборку и строю дерево по parent . Задача: в столбец sum добавить значение value собственного поля и прибавить значение value вложенных строк. Что нужно сюда добавить и как это сделать именно через PHP??
Код дерева:

```
Вытягивание данных с таблицы
function getTree(){
    global $link;
    $query = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT name , email , value , sum FROM data");
    $result = [];
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $result[$row["parent"]][] = $row;
    }
    return $result;
}

$tree_arr = getTree();


Построение дерева
function showTree($parent , $level){
    global $tree_arr;
    if (isset($tree_arr[$parent])){
        foreach($tree_arr[$parent] as $value){

            echo "<div style='margin-left:" . ($level * 25) . "px; '>" .
                $value["name"] . ",email=" . $value["email"] . ",value=" . $value["value"] .',sum=' . $value['sum'] . "</div>";
            $level = $level + 1;
            showTree($value["id"], $level);
            $level = $level - 1;
        }
    }
}

showTree(0,0);
```

Сама таблица , никаких связей нет
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuedZ.png

Comment: начните с того, чтобы просто выбрать все данные нужные для построения. не надо это делать на каждом уровне для каждого листа

Comment: @teran , разделил код на 2 функции , в первой функции у меня выбираются данные и записываются в двумерный массив , во 2 функции у меня идет построение дерева по ключу

Comment: сумму значений в поддереве надо считать при возврате из рекурсивной функции. А выводить при входе. так что за один раз это сделать не получится.
В целом, не надо пихать строки в результат по parent_id. Это, вероятно, несколько усложнит задачу. Сначал просто извлеките их. Потом пройдитесь циклом и распихайте их по родителям используя ссылки. Потом напишите рекурсию, посчитав суммы от корня дерева. Потом уже выводите его.